# Inserting Jquery var into append input value

Tags: jquery, append, var

I'm trying to take an input value, create a variable out of it, and insert it into and append later in the function. I had it working for a bit, changes something, and now it's only returning the var name... and it's driving me insane. See code.

HTML (i'm looking at the new-task input)

```
<div class="add-task">
<h3>Add a task</h3>
<form id="todo-form">
    <input id="new-task" type="text" placeholder="Define task" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="How long with this take? (00:00)" />
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Add Task" />
</form>
</div>
```

JS: (i'm looking at add newTask var into the value for task-name)

```
$('.button').on('click', function (){
var newTask = $('#new-task').val();
console.log(newTask)
$('.task-container').append('<ul><li class=\"task-list\"><img class=\"checkmark\" src=\"img/checkmark.jpeg\" alt=\"Checkmark-Button\"><input class=\"task-name\" value=+newTask+><input class=\"task-time\" value=\"1:00\"><img class=\"X\" src=\"img/X.png\" alt=\"X-Button\"></li></ul>');
```

});

Comment: Maybe it's the total lack of a `.task-container` element ?

Comment: Also concatenation has a problem here. need to break the string using `'` before appending a variable into it. And there is no need to escape `"` when you are using it inside `'`

Answer (score 1):

As **Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy** said, you forgot quotes around newTask in your append :

```
$('.task-container').append('<ul><li class="task-list"><img class="checkmark" src="img/checkmark.jpeg" alt="Checkmark-Button"><input class="task-name" value="'+newTask+'"><input class="task-time" value="1:00"><img class="X" src="img/X.png" alt="X-Button"></li></ul>');
```

[It works !](https://jsfiddle.net/xquoofre/)

Answer (score -1):

$(this).parents("tr").children("td:eq(1)").empty()
.html($(".txt_name").show().val(text1));